# Design of double linked Parent - Child relation

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list

I have defined a C#-class, that shall be the elements of a directed graph (basically a tree, but an element can have multiple parents - I do not know if there is a special name for that).

Each element shall now all its children and all its parents. It exposes those lists as IEnumarable

```
public interface IMyClass
{
  public IEnumerable<MyClass> Children { get; }
  public IEnumerable<MyClass> Parents { get; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  private List<MyClass> _parents;
  private List<MyClass> _children;

  public IEnumerable<MyClass> Children
  {
    get { foreach (var child in _children) yield return child; }
  }

  public IEnumerable<MyClass> Parents
  {
    get { foreach (var parent in _parents) yield return parent; }
  }
```

When adding or removing a child to a given element, I want to make sure, that the given element is added or removed to the parents list of the child too.

First idea was to only expose an AddChild(MyClass theChild) method. Problem is, that I can't add the parent to the theChild object because it doesn't expose an AddParent(parent) method and I can't call private methods of the theChild-object.

So I tried to go with exposing an AddParent(MyClass theParent) method too. To still make sure that both objects links are set, my first shot was calling the AddParent/AddChild in the other function like this:

```
public void AddChild(IMyClass theChild)
{
  _children.Add(theChild);
  theChild.AddParent(this);
}

public void AddParent(IMyClass theParent)
{
  _parent.Add(theParent);
  theParent.AddChild(this);
}
```

but obviously, that is a deadly loop.

To make things worse, I want to allow that an element can be the child of another element multiple times (this isn't a requirement yet, but I want to make sure, that WHEN this requirement comes, my code need not to be touched.)

Are there any algorithms / standard approaches that allow me to make sure, that when adding a child to the parent always **both** object links are set?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Edith: Added the interfaces to correct the example.

Comment: IMHO it's a design-flaw. 1.) Why can a child have multiple parents? 2.) Why do they have to know about the parents? Is it _really_ neccessary?

Comment: Saying it's a design flaw without knowing how it's used doesn't make sense.  There's no reason to think this isn't valid and the perfect solution to the problem he's using

Comment: In my experience such loops often appear where the design is... well, flawed. I usually find them where they are used because the programmer i.e. had a list of objects and wanted to know which control it belonged to. Solution => Add a "Control" property to the object (create the loop) instead of using a fitting way to store the control<->object relations. I _never_ found a valid use for this except in double-linked lists. I agree that i might be wrong though, my apologies.

Comment: 1.) For example, look at Wikipedia categories. They can have multiple parent categories. In my case, an object that is represented by a node in my "tree" can appear at different branches. If I would let a child have only one parent, I'd need to have copies of that object at each position and need to propagate each change to all copied objects. 2) When I change an attribute of a child it can affect the state of the parent. I need to check if this happens so I need to get all parent objects. 3) No need for apologies! I am happy about all input that may help me find a good solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public void AddChild(MyClass theChild)
{
    _children.Add(theChild);
    theChild._parent.Add(this);
}

public void AddParent(MyClass theParent)
{
    _parent.Add(theParent);
    theParent._children.Add(this);
}
```

There should be no problems with that; just because you're referring to a different instance of the class you're writing the method for doesn't mean you can't access it's members (even if they are private).

---

OK with the revised code, you can add two new members to your interface: `NotifyChildAdded` and `NotifyParentAdded`, and implement like this:

```
public void AddChild(MyClass theChild)
{
    _children.Add(theChild);
    theChild.NotifyParentAdded(this);
}

public void AddParent(MyClass theParent)
{
    _parent.Add(theParent);
    theParent.NotifyChildAdded(this);
}

public void NotifyChildAdded(MyClass theChild)
{
    _children.Add(theChild);
}

public void NotifyParentAdded(MyClass theParent)
{
    _parent.Add(theParent);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: oops, I simplified too much. In my project I do not work with the classes itself, but with Interfaces, that those classes implement. Thus, my parameter for the Add...method is an interface, so I cannot access the private variables of the class. Sorry, my fault! I'll correct the code in an instant.

Comment: Thanks Kieren! My problem with this approach is, that the Notify-methods are public methods and therefor any object - not only the Add...methods - could call them. So it would be possible, that not both links are set.

Answer (score 0):

*... but I want to make sure, that WHEN this requirement comes, my code need not to be touched.*
That's a clear violation of the YAGNI-principle ([you ain't gonna need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it)). Maybe you should just start to code it the way you need it right now (that means using `Contains()` ^^). And care about changes to your requirement when they come ...

Comment: I do not exactly add a "feature", I just try to build a robust datamodel, that could handle such feature change. But the point you mentioned is the same, I guess (and valid anyway!). My fear is that I need to change the basic datamodel someday in the future and therefor all my other logic building on top of this crumbles. But if that'd made it increasingly complex (and thereby error-prone), I will go back to where I am able to use the Contains() :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to expose the list properties as internal, and have public add methods that will call access the internal properties of the other class.

Another option is to have dumb data and a separate business logic layer which is what outside code calls.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible design is to store the relationship between the nodes in the Graph object rather than embedding this information in the Node objects.  If you still want to operate from the Node classes, you can pass an interface for the Graph to the Nodes so that they can provide 'convenience' functions like GetParents(), GetChildren(), AddParent(), AddChild() that call the appropriate public Graph functions.  The idea here is that the Nodes shouldn't be responsible for managing Graph operations; this should be the Graph's responsibility.

One simple implementation is an adjacency matrix.  This is an NxN boolean array where N is the number of nodes and the contents of A[i,j] indicates whether there is a link from node i to node j.  This makes updating parent/child relationships O(1) (simply set/reset a flag) and makes enumerating parents and children for a given node O(N).  The downside is that you use O(N^2) space.  This is a good approach if you want to mutate the graph frequently.  It also generalizes to a weighted graph if you store weights instead of flags.

You can use a 'list of lists' type of approach if you want to conserve space.  This is really only beneficial if the number of links is much smaller than the number of nodes (i.e. the graph is sparsely connected) and the number of nodes is large.